# Must a valid SSL/TLS certificate include "client authentication" purpose (OID 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2)?

Tags: iis, certificate-authority, ssl-certificate-errors

In other words, could the missing "client authentication" purpose in our CA-issued SSL cert be the reason it's not trusted by browsers?

If so, how do I add that purpose / OID in a CSR (Certificate Signing Request) or during certificate issuance in AD CA (Active Directory Certification Authority)?

Reason I ask:

Most working (trusted) SSL certs I looked at, including for outlook.com:

[image: outlook.com SSL cert]

... has two "purposes" / extended key usage field values / OIDs listed, "client" and "server":

```
TLS WWW Server Authentication (OID.1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1)
TLS WWW Client Authentication (OID.1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2)
```

... whereas a local root CA-issued non-working (`NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` error) SSL cert that I am [trying to get to work](https://superuser.com/q/1809986/239558), has a "server" but not a "client" one:

[image: local root CA issued SSL cert]

Granted, some working SSL certs (e.g. for gmail.com and google.com) also only have a server auth purpose / OID but not a "client" one. Just wanted to rule this out as a possible reason for why my SSL certs are not trusted.

[image: google.com SSL cert]

Thanks!

P.S. A self-signed (rather than local CA-issued) SSL cert is working (trusted) on the intranet site in question, so the issue is not with IIS or bindings. Rather, it's with one of the certificates or the trust chain - I am just not sure how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: No, clientAuth in EKU is not required for server, BUT **SAN (SubjectAlternativeName) IS REQUIRED for _HTTPS_ server** (and must correctly match the name used by the browser or other client to access the server)

Comment: You might run a report to iron out common issues, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html